# Extracting fix of GitHub issues using GitHub API

Tags: github, github-api

I am trying to extract Pull Requests (PR)/commits that fix a closed GitHub issue using GitHub API. When you look at GitHub UI representation of Issue, you may see "Fixed by XXX" on top of the page (as shown in the figure which is related to https://github.com/broadinstitute/gatk/issues/7696). But there is not information regarding this fix in GitHub API info. Do you have any ideas to extract information regarding GitHub issue fixes using API?

[image]